# how to set name of my choice in downloading file from Url

Tags: java, android

I want to set name of my choice in downloading file from Url.

```
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(URL));
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your file name in subPath

```
  val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or 
    DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
    request.setTitle("Download")
    request.setDescription("The File is Downloading..")
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
    request.setMimeType("application/pdf")
    request.setNotificationVisibility
   (DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
        "${System.currentTimeMillis()}" + ".pdf")

    // get download service and  enqueue file
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    manager.enqueue(request)
```

Comment: you're welcome :) , please upvote the answer and accept it to make it easier for other people to find it

Comment: I DON'T HAVE ENOUGH REPUTATION FOR VOTE. SORRY!!!